# Google Sheet Script Editor: only logging first character of key in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-sheets

I am trying to loop through an array of objects using Script Editor in Google Sheets. However, when I log the variable 'temp', it only returns the first letter of the first key of the first object in the array. I tried converting everything to a string using the TO_TEXT function, but it produced the same result.

I've looked through Google forums and can not find anything that pointed to a solution to this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

The purpose of this project is to loop through a set data and identify if a particular action occurred that does not have a corresponding action. For instance, if a user viewed something, but did not also update that same thing, I want to push the object where the action was solely viewing into a separate array.

```html
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Security Risk Audit - users')
    .addItem('Perform user audit', 'getSheetData')
    .addToUi();
}




var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var allSheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var fileName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();
var headerRow = allSheetData[0];
var data = [];
var filteredData = [];


function getSheetData (){
  
  
  for (var currentRow = 1; currentRow < allSheetData.length; currentRow++){
    
    var obj = {};
    
    for (var rowColumn = 0; rowColumn<headerRow.length; rowColumn++){
      
      obj[headerRow[rowColumn]]=allSheetData[currentRow][rowColumn];
    }
    
    data.push(obj);
  }
  filterData();

}

function filterData() {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){     
    var temp = data[i].patientid[i];
    Logger.log(temp);
    for(var j = 0; j<data.length; j++) {
      if(temp == data[j].patientid[j] && data[j].type[j] == "view"){
        var temp2 = data[j].patientid[j];
      } else {
        return false;
      }
      for (var k = 0; k<data.length;k++){
        if(temp2 == data[k].patientid[k] && data[k].type[k] != "view") {
           return false;
        }else{
           filteredData.push(data[k]);
        }
      }    
    }
  }
  return filteredData;
}
```

Comment: That is probably because `data[i].patientid` is a string not an array. If that is the case, doing `data[i].patientid[i]` will just log the character at index `i` from the string `data[i].patientid`.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks for your help.